# eclipse/tizen studio - jquery error although jquery works fine

Tags: jquery, eclipse, tizen

I am working on an eclipse version provided by the Tizen IDE .

Jquery works , but i have a constant error appears on IDE saying : `$ is not defined` .

The error appears on each occurrence of  the `$` / (Jquery) in code , so basically my eclipse workplace looks like a big mess.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which one are you using Tizen IDE or Tizen Studio ?

Comment: only tizen studio

Comment: You can check this post https://developer.tizen.org/forums/sdk-ide/jquery-not-defined-error

Answer (score 0):

Tizen Studio uses **JSHint** to validate Your Javascript code by default.

To inform this validator that `$` is a global variable (defined outside the file) simply add

```
/* globals $ */
```

on the top in the file where You use `$`